# HttpServlet: doPut is not called

Tags: java, iphone, http, servlets, put

I have a Tomcat application server and this Java source code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public MyServlet() {}

    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ... PUT code
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ... GET code
    }
}
```

With GET everything is fine. The method `doGet` is called. But from my iPhone app doing a put the `doPut` method is not called. Nothing happens on the server, I see nothing in the log files. So what´s wrong? Are there any PUT limitations on Tomcat?
How can I debug this? On the iOS device I use a library which I can tell that PUT shall be used, so it should work, because it is a very common framework.

Does anyone have an idea?

Best Regards Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to trace the packets to make sure you actually get a PUT request.

Or similarly [setup a separate access log for tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) (it is already in the default config file, but commented out I believe) to see what is coming in.

If you open in your favorit texteditor the file **conf/server.xml** in the tomcat directory then you'll find near the end :

```
    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
    -->
```

if you remove the comment tokens all access will be logged to **logs/localhost_access_log**.

e.g. :

```
    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Comment: How can I do this with the separate access log? Where it is commented out?

Comment: I added a link to the tomcat docs. It consists of enabling the AccessLogValve. Very useful tool.

Comment: Very helpful, I found the problem. It was not sent to the server :-( But only with your help, I located the problem.

Answer (score 0):

doPut() is a valid method, but more likely you want to execute a doPost() instead.

HTTP defines GET, POST and PUT (amongst others), but in general GET is used for accessing pages whereas POST is used for posting data.

You can get more details on the definition of these verbs at:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: This is a more likely explanation, unless the OP is uploading files via a RESTful interface.

Comment: Its certainly possible that PUT is required instead of POST, but probably unlikely.  What is the client library being used on the iOS device?